# determinant involving unitary hermitian matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant

Let $S$ be the set of complex $N\times N$ matrices that are both unitary and hermitian.

I have observed the following fact. For any pair of matrices $A$, $B$ from $S$, the value of $\det(A+iB)$ is an imaginary number if $N \equiv 2 \text{ mod } 4$.

Any ideas how to prove this?

All I could do was compute 
$$\det(A+iB)^*=\det(A^\dagger-iB^\dagger)=\det(A^{-1}-iB^{-1})=\det(A-iB),$$ but this did not help me much.

Comment: Try putting $A=B=I$.

Comment: @user647486 the fact does not hold for all dimensions, sorry

Comment: Take $A=\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\0&-1\end{pmatrix}$ and $B=I$.

Comment: Without computing a thing it was always clear that the property is obviously false, since an analytic function that returns values on a line must be constant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider$$[\det(A+iB)]^2=\det[(A+iB)^2]=\det[A^2+iAB+iBA-B^2]\tag1$$Now note that due to $A$ (similar for $B$) being Hermitian, $A^\dagger=A$. Due to unitarity, $A^\dagger=A^{-1}$. Combining, $$A=A^{-1}\implies A^2=\Bbb I$$ So $(1)$ becomes $$i^n\det(AB+BA)$$ If $n\equiv2\mod4$, then $i^n=-1$. So $$[\det(A+iB)]^2=-\det(AB+BA)\tag2$$ Thus, if we can show that $\det(AB+BA)\ge0$ for all $A,B\in S$, then your hypothesis holds. However, inspired by user647468's comment, we can take $B=\Bbb I\in S$, and $A_{ij}=(-1)^{i+1}\delta_{ij}$. Then $$\det(AB+BA)=2^n\prod_{i=1}^{n}(-1)^{i+1}=-2^n<0\tag3$$Hence the $RHS$ of $(2)$ *can* be positive, and so $\det(A+iB)$ is not necessarily imaginary.